# How do I change a component name in Eagle?

Tags: eaglecad

Looking to change R3 and R4 to R1 and R2. Not sure which button to press on the schematic to edit the values of the different resistors.

Answer (score 2):

There is a button with 'R2 / 10k', with the 'R2' in bold, and which has the tool tip 'Name', in the tool bar.

Choose it, then select the components you want to rename. That will pop up a dialogue with the components existing name. Type the new name in the dialogue.

It will *not* let you change any name to an existing name (on a different component). So it will not allow R1 to be renamed R3 directly, if R3 is already a component name.

To *swap* names: 'Name' R1 to something currently unused, e.g. R103, then 'Name' R3 to e.g. R1, then finally 'Name' R103 to R3.

There is an thorough online help system with Eagle, with a search. That often answers these types of questions.

Comment: Selecting the component doesn't work. I'm trying to select a resistor by clicking on it and the computer just bleeps at me. Don't know what's wrong.